# Mat-select won't arrow navigate when auto-opened after opening a modal

Tags: angular, angular-material, focus

I have a mat-select located in a modal. Currently I have it setup so that after opening the modal, it will run open() on the mat-select so that the select list is expanded, however when doing this I am unable to use up and down arrow keys to navigate the list like you normally would unless I hit tab first so it appears to be some sort of focus problem.

This code opens the mat-select list after the modal is opened.

```
this.dialogRef.afterOpened().pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(() => {
      if (this.exampleSelect) {
        this.exampleSelect.open();
      }
 });
```

Here is the mat select in question

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-select  #exampleSelect formControlName="exampleSelect" ariaLabel="Example Selector" required>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let exampleSelectOption of exampleSelectOptions">
                <mat-option [value]="exampleSelectOption.value">
                  {{ exampleSelectOption.description }}
                </mat-option>
              </ng-container>
            </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add** `@ViewChildren("option") options: QueryList<ElementRef>;` at typescript.

**Change** the `if` statement to:

```
if (this.exampleSelect) {
    this.exampleSelect.open();
    this.exampleSelect._elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
    this.options.toArray()[0].nativeElement.focus();
}
```

**Add** `#option` at `mat-option`

```
<mat-option #option [value]="exampleSelectOption.value">
    {{ exampleSelectOption.description }}
</mat-option>
```

You may also try skipping the line: `this.exampleSelect._elementRef.nativeElement.focus();`

It may work. Not 100% sure.